# Search results - detail pane

Tags: search

I realise this probably requires custom development, but curious if anyone has considered a two pane search results, where the left pane is the listing and the right pane a detailed contact record.  The aim is to improve/speed up navigation for user looking at records.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you mouse over the icon on the left of each result row a popup comes up with more details on the contact. This does help isolating the correct record when reviewing results.